# Need way to view an album of pictures on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I don't need to take pictures or access the iPhone photo album.  I simply need to display a bunch of pictures in thumbnail form and then let the user view the larger version when tapped.

Would I use an uiimagepickercontroller or another controller?

If so does anyone have an example of how I load in the pictures to view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the same tools that the facebook app uses: three20

Joe Hewitt, the developer behind the facebook app has open sourced much of his work. You can get it and many other goodies here: http://github.com/joehewitt/three20